# How to force a browser to download page content resources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, html, browser-cache

Too frequently I see issues where customers/clients have to refresh the webpage, typically after clearing their history/cache, only to find out that the webpage is perfectly fine.

Is there any way to add a version or just force the browser to download all resources, such as scripts, images, ...etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way to do this is to append a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) or version number to the URL of these resources:

```
myStylesheet.css?ver=1.1

logo.png?ver=13.1
```

When you change the file, you update the version number and any cached resource gets updated.

You can also ensure you are using the same version number (or whatever) for every time you make any changes to the codebase.